# PHP equivalent to site.master?

Tags: php, html, server-side-includes

One of the nice things about ASP.Net is the ability to set a `site.master` file that holds all the repeated HTML/code from a site, and still be able to alter things on it from an individual website page. (For example, changing the `<title>` tag for every page, or adding other things to the `<head>` of your document.)

In the past in PHP I've used Server Side Includes to remove duplicate HTML/code (such as the top of the document, main navigation, footer, etc.) but obviously you can't alter any of the contents from the page.

Is there any way to implement `site.master` type functionality in PHP? **If not**, what's a good way to remove repeated HTML/code while still being able to change things like the page's title, highlighted navigation, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of pulling in common fragments is to use `require()` which will allow you to include other files within the current file.

An example of how you might use it:

**header.php** - a reusable fragment

```
<div class="header">
    <h1><?= $pageTitle ?></h1>
</div>
```

**pageContents.php**

```
<body>
<?php
$pageTitle = 'Check it out, the Foobar page!';
require('header.php');
?>
blah blah
</body>
```

Comment: Yes. The fragments you require in need not be static. "obviously you can't alter any of the contents from the page" is wrong, you can define vars in the parent page and have them echoed in child pages.

Comment: Could you give me an example in your answer, because I don't understand how you could use a require() to bring in the top of every page (for example) but then alter the page's title. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent. This seems to be the quickest and easiest way for me to implement what I want. Thank you!

Comment: I've put it in a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930466/php-passing-variable-to-an-include/5930476#5930476

Comment: Replace the `<?=` with `<?php echo `

Answer (score 4):

This is just called Template Engine and there is tons of engine for php.

Smarty is one of them

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is obviously a very common need. Do most programmers use Template Engines when they're making a site in PHP?

Comment: From the research I've done it appears most programmers do not like using Smarty, or other Template Engines, as PHP is already good enough.

Comment: @django: most programmers **LIKE** to use a template engine, now if it's smarty or w/e doens't matter. Your research skill failed there xD

Comment: What do you make of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605/php-as-a-template-language-or-some-other-php-templating-script/

Comment: Of course. It says that PHP is fine without a Template Engine, but "if you don't trust the other folks who may be working on this code, you may have to force them to use something like Smarty." I'm the only programmer.

Comment: That means in your template engine you don't have to invent a new syntax (like smarty does) but in your template engine you can freely use PHP. But this doesn't preclude the fact you should use a template engine ( or just if you want: split the presentation from business logic ) And saying a template engine I mean even just the function in the second answer of your link

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a templating engine built for PHP.  ASP is a framework which has templating built in which provides you the functionality that you are referring to (i..e templates, membership provider, etc.)

In order to get the same in PHP you will need to use either a framework or a templating engine.

Some samples:

- http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/
- http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Answer (score 0):

there is no such functionality in PHP, you can move your components into separate files and include them in your main file using `include` or `require` functions.

Some frameworks do provide (simulate) such functionality though. e.g. In cakePHP you can have a layout file where you can output your pages.