# Passing variable to an include

Tags: php, server-side-includes

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $title = "This is the page title";
    require_once '/includes/header.php';
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<head>
    <title><?= $title ?></title>
</head>
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think short tags may not be enabled. Try:

```
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
```

instead

Comment: This was it. I'll mark as the answer as soon as SO allows me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

did you enable short tags in php.ini?

[short link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: +1 No sir, I did not. Doh. But even writing <?php= $title ?> doesn't work.

Comment: well, I've never tried `<?php=$title?>` how about `<?php echo $title;?>`

Comment: `<?php= $title ?>` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

My only thought is that you have short tags disabled in your php.ini.

Try the following:

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: James C beat you by 10 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your PHP for [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)